# Isn't there a way to have Feeds XML parsers populate the alt text?

Tags: feeds

I am building a site and I'm using xml because I feel its more extensible. I have multiple images being imported and I have a special tag  for the captions as well but there is not a direct way that I can reference the caption to the image. Below is an example of my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Republikein>
<content> 
<category>Verkiesings</category>
<headline>Oorwin, meen ontleders send version </headline>
<author>Dani Booysen</author>
<story>Die finansiële vakbond NBWU het onlangs 'n ondersoek onderneem om vas te stel of versekeringsverteenwoordigers wel werknemers van versekeringsmaatskappye is of nie.
</story>
<image imageid="6985">/var2/www/html/images/Hage-triomfeer-3.jpg</image>
<imagecaption imageid="6985">This is the first captione for  image </imagecaption>
<imagecredit imageid="6985">MARLIZE RAUTENBACH</imagecredit>
<imageid>6985</imageid>
<image imageid="6986">/var2/www/html/images/Rede-het-oorwin-3.jpg</image>
<imagecaption imageid="6986"></imagecaption>
<imagecredit imageid="6986">MARLIZE RAUTENBACH</imagecredit>
<imageid>6986</imageid>
<image imageid="6988">/var2/www/html/images/Bloed-vloei-3.jpg</image>
<imagecaption imageid="6988">Thsi image has a caption too... opk..image#6988 .lol</imagecaption>
<imagecredit imageid="6988">MARLIZE RAUTENBACH</imagecredit>
<imageid>6988</imageid>
<edition>Republikein</edition>
<volume>36</volume>
<volumenumber>1</volumenumber>
<page>12</page>
<publisheddate>1354516920</publisheddate>
<keywords>Afrikaans,Dutch</keywords> 
</content>
</Republikein>
```

As you can see I have my xml with a lot of information. My problem is that the xml xpath parser does not read the attributes as an alternative to use that for alt text for image and nor does the module provide a way to link the captions to the images.

If you have gone this road before your help will be appreciated. Also note that I have tried to use the token module as a replacement pattern for the image caption file, but it take all the caption and bulks them on all the images. So in this case, all images will have 3 captions. This seems easy but I'm importing 4600 nodes and a manual approach is out of the question.